# Algebraic isolation of integer with power function attached

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{T_3}{T_2}=\left(\frac{P_3}{P_2}\right)^{\frac{R}{C_p}}$$

I need to find $P_3$, I'm not sure how to deal with the power function?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{T_3}{T_2}=\left(\frac{P_3}{P_2}\right)^{\frac{R}{C_p}}\Rightarrow \frac{P_3}{P_2}=\left(\frac{T_3}{T_2}\right)^{\frac{C_p}{R}}\Rightarrow P_3=P_2\left(\frac{T_3}{T_2}\right)^{\frac{C_p}{R}}.$$